# How to pretty-print elapsed times/ETAs in Python?

Tags: python, elapsedtime

I am measuring run times of a program in seconds. Depending on the amount of data I input, that can take milliseconds to days. Is there a Python module that I can use to convert the number of seconds to the most useful unit and display that? Approximations are fine.

For example, 50 should become `50 seconds`, 590 should become `10 minutes`, `100000` should become `1 day` or something like that. I could write the basic thing myself, but I am sure people have thought about this more than I have and have considered many of the edge case I wouldn't think about in a 1000 years :)

Edit: I noticed `tqdm` must have some logic associated with that, as it selects the length of the ETA string accordingly. Compare

```
for _ in tqdm.tqdm(range(10)): time.sleep(1)
```

with

```
for _ in tqdm.tqdm(range(100000)): time.sleep(1)
```

Edit: I have also found this Gist, but I would prefer code with at least some maintanence :)
https://gist.github.com/alexwlchan/73933442112f5ae431cc

Answer (score 2):

Close the question if you want, `humanize.naturaldelta` is the answer:

> This modest package contains various common humanization utilities, like turning a number into a fuzzy human readable duration ('3 minutes ago') or into a human readable size or throughput. It works with python 2.7 and 3.3 and is localized to Russian, French, Korean and Slovak.

https://github.com/jmoiron/humanize

Answer (score 2):

I just found [arrow](https://github.com/crsmithdev/arrow):

> Arrow is a Python library that offers a sensible and human-friendly approach to creating, manipulating, formatting and converting dates, times and timestamps.

It has humanize(), too, and is much more well-maintainted, it seems:
https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#humanize